# Java generics how to avoid unsafe casts warnings when populating a parameterized type via interface and then using it in a Consumer

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to resolve an issue that bugs me and looks like a bad code smell.
Consider the following implementation, where the main purpose is to retrieve a list of tuples that have a mapping of a generic ContainerA and a generic ContainerB that utilize the same object as type parameter which implement the same marker interface (MyInterface) for grouping types. The code that populates the list of these tuples is shown below:

```
  private static final List<Tuple2<ContainerA<MyInterface>, ContainerB<MyInterface>>>
      listOfMappings = new ArrayList<>();

  public static List<Tuple2<ContainerA<MyInterface>, ContainerB<MyInterface>>>
      getMapping() {
    listOfMappings.add(
        createMappingTuple(new ContainerA<ObjectImplMyInterface>(), new ContainerB<ObjectImplMyInterface>()));
    listOfMappings.add(
        createMappingTuple(new ContainerA<AnotherObjectImplMyInterface>(), new ContainerB<AnotherObjectImplMyInterface>()));
  }

  private static <T extends MyInterface>
      Tuple2<ContainerA<T>, ContainerB<T>> createMappingTuple(
          ContainerA<? extends MyInterface> containerInstanceA,
          ContainerB<? extends MyInterface> containerInstanceB) {

    Tuple2<ContainerA<T>, ContainerB<T>> tuple = new Tuple2<>();
    tuple.f0 = (ContainerA<T>) containerInstanceA;
    tuple.f1 = (ContainerB<T>) containerInstanceB;
    return tuple;
  }
```

Note that the code above has unsafe casts and generates warnings as below which should be
expected based on casting

```
Unchecked cast: 'ContainerA<capture<? extends MyInterface>>' to 'ContainerA<T>'
```

I could make implementation above use parameter Type <? extends MyInterface> for the list of tuples to avoid these warnings but that would not help my cause since I need to use this list of tuples on another piece of code where ContainerB is used by a Consumer (and therefore it should follow the <? super MyInterface>), as for example you can see in the following snippet:

```
for (Tuple2<ContainerA<MyInterface>, ContainerB<MyInterface>>
            currentTuple : listOfMappings) {

    currentTuple.f0
      .extract(...)
      .forEach(r -> context.send(currentTuple.f1, r));
 }
```

Is there a way to refactor the code to avoid these warnings or does it make sense (is it safe ?) to suppress them since they do not appear to have any effect on code ?

Comment: Can you show `MyInterface`?

Comment: MyInterface is a marker interface and therefore empty it is just used to group all objects under the same umbrella

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that part. What type is `r` and what is the signature of `context.send` then? I don't see the connection of "used by a consumer" and `<? super MyInterface>`. The PECS rule is that you should make it `<? super MyInterface>` if the type parameter is used *as* a consumer, not "by"...

Comment: Yes you are correct, I should rephrase that. By the way the signature for the method is ```<X> void send(ContainerB<X> output, X value)``` and is basic a call to an external API